# 'QOAuth::Interface& QOAuth::Interface::operator=(const QOAuth::Interface&)' is private

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to use QOAuth but received following error:

error: 'QOAuth::Interface& QOAuth::Interface::operator=(const QOAuth::Interface&)' is private

My source code is as follows:

service.h

```
// ...
class Service : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

// ...

private:
    QOAuth::Interface *qoauth;
};
// ...
```

service.cpp

```
#include "service.h"

Service::Service(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
*qoauth = new QOAuth::Interface;
}

QString Service::getAuthorizeUrl(QString consumerKey, QString consumerSecret){

    // set the consumer key and secret
    qoauth->setConsumerKey(consumerKey);
    qoauth->setConsumerSecret(bytes);

    // ...
}

void Service::accessToken(QString url) {
    // send a request to exchange Request Token for an Access Token
    QOAuth::ParamMap reply = qoauth->accessToken(url, QOAuth::POST, m_token, m_tokenSecret, QOAuth::HMAC_SHA1);

    // ...
}
```

I don't understand pointer enough and it may be the cause...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*qoauth = new QOAuth::Interface;` is not correct since `new` returns a *pointer* to the object it should be `qoauth = new QOAuth::Interface;`

Comment: Thank you and sorry for late reply. I tried `qoauth = new QOAuth::Interface` then compiler complained that "base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'QOAuth::Interface'" for e.g. `qoauth->setConsumerKey(consumerKey);` If I changed it dot operator and compiler said "no matching function for call to 'QOAuth::Interface::setConsumerKey(QString&)'". Which is correct...?